# Laravel 5 app keeps using old database connection

Tags: laravel-5

```
PDOExceptionvendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:47

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I have updated .env file with the correct credentials (its not even localhost anymore, its an IP address) however I keep getting this error message. I have already run `php artisan config:clear` as well too. How can I force a production app to use the new credentials in its .env file?

My config/database.php is standard:

```
'connections' => [
       'mysql' => [
           'driver'    => 'mysql',
           'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
           'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE'),
           'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME'),
           'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
           'port'      => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
           'charset'   => 'utf8',
           'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
           'prefix'    => '',
           'strict'    => false,
    ],

],
```

Comment: Show your `env` and `config/database.php` files.

Comment: posted, the keys in .env match with this, the DB_HOST is not localhost anymore, but it keeps trying to connect to that.

Comment: Try running `composer update`

Comment: In my case i just had to serve my project again as i was working on localhost. So "php artisan serve" worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good lord, almost lost my mind trying fix this. There was no problem with the DB connection on the web requests, but I was still getting connection errors in my bug reporting. Seems the issue was the queue we were running was holding the old config values.

`ps aux | grep php`

Find the `queue:work` process and kill it, it will start up again automatically but read in your new config values.

Answer (score 15):

Run the following Artisan commands then try again:

```
php artisan cache:clear

php artisan config:clear

php artisan config:cache

php artisan route:clear

php artisan route:cache
```

Comment: This actually helped me. I was having jobs in queue that were using the old .env records. I think the command that actually helped was `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 2):

.env file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=SomeRandomString

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
```

config/database.php

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
],
```

Comment: I have this now.. I've even removed the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Please remove the file `config.php` from the mentioned path `project_name\bootstrap\cache`
[image: Marked file & folder path]

**Step 2:** Now, Run the commands which are mentioned below:

```
 composer dump-autoload
 php artisan clear-compiled
 php artisan config:clear
 php artisan cache:clear

 php artisan config:cache
```

Hope, it will work for you.