# Laravel 5.5: Production environment logging into MySQL with local credentials though .env and database.php are set up for my distant mysql server

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.5

Hello dear StackOverflow community!

This is my first time operating a Laravel deployment, and I'm running into issues that probably have a simple answer that I couldn't find after many hours of research.

Laravel is returning an error `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory` when I look at my production homepage, and I was able to track down the issue with the Database by using the following SSH command:
`mysqladmin -u root -p status`
Which returns:

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
```

So it seems Laravel logs into my local .env values, yet I only have one .env file that is configured for production on the server:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=my_distant_mysql_server_domain
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database_name
DB_USERNAME=user_name
DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxx
```

I also configured database.php, to no avail:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
[...]
        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'my_distant_mysql_server_domain'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'database_name'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'user_name'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxxxxxxx'),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

Is anyone here aware of something I might have missed?

I also tried all the resolutions offered in this thread, but my issue persists:
[Laravel 5 app keeps using old database connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30609092/laravel-5-app-keeps-using-old-database-connection)

Unfortunately I have to use the mysql server domain name, and not the IP, as my hosting doesn't provide any IP.

Thank you very much for your help on this matter :)

Comment: Pretty sure you want to remove the `unix_socket` from the config for a remote MySQL server.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have already tried that as well :/ Editing my post, sorry!

Comment: Well actually, I didn't try re-running the php artisan commands right after I removed the sockets! This worked!! Thanks a bunch, @ChrisWhite :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Chris, I realized this issue came from the fact I didn't remove the socket config while trying to connect to a remote database, before then (important step!) re-running the following commands:

```
php artisan cache:clear

php artisan config:clear

php artisan config:cache

php artisan route:clear

php artisan route:cache
```

Doing those two steps solved my issue :)