# Laravel keeps connecting to old database connection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**Context :**

- I have DB1 and DB2 and a laravel application using DB1 so far
- I want now that laravel (8) application to use DB2 instead (both DB1 & 2 are mysql)
- I edited the .env file to change the DB_HOST and cleared the config cache

**Expected** : Laravel using DB2

**Problem** : Laravel still connects to DB1

**Things I've tried** :

- `php artisan config:cache` / clear
- `php artisan optimize:clear`
- restarted DB1/DB2
- restarted nginx
- restarted php-fpm
- redeployed the whole app (with composer install etc.)
- tried adding a new connection in `config/database.php` instead of editing the existing one : same issue
- hardcoding the values in `config/database.php` instead of referencing the env file : same issue
- `php artisan db sql` --> connects to the RIGHT DB (this is what's driving me insane)
- ... but php artisan tinker doesn't seem to. I created a dummy table in DB2 only (so not present in DB1) and getting that table with `\DB::connection('mysql')->table('dummy')->get();` shows an error via tinker
- obviously, stopping DB1 makes the application go offline ("No such file or directory" blabla ie. no database PDO)

I don't even know what to try anymore. Every post somewhat related online are solved after a simple `artisan config:clear/cache` ....

Any thoughts appreciated ?

Comment: By any chance, are you running any queue process? You can simply find it using **queue:work** .  Find the queue:work process and kill it. The original answer is from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30609092/laravel-5-app-keeps-using-old-database-connection)

Comment: Might also help if you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73309360/edit) to include your `.env` file for your `DB_*` keys, as well as `config/database.php`. Replace anything sensitive with `****` before posting, but that should help us debug what is happening. `php artisan tinker` is a good way to test, as it is a new/fresh connection each time it is run.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was `DB_SOCKET=/tmp/mysql.sock` in my .env file that locked the connection to the previous (local) DB. Removing that from my env file solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

In case the other answers do not solve this for you, you can try to manually delete the cache in `./bootstrap/cache/config.php` and `./bootstrap/cache/_config.php`. For some reason in my case `php artisan config:cache` didn't seem to be clearing the cache. This was on an older version of Laravel (5.2.45 to be exact).

Answer (score -1):

to change the database you need to write the database name on DB_DATABASE instead on DB_HOST...

Comment: I want to connect to a different DB_HOST, database name is the same

Comment: https://www.learn2torials.com/a/laravel-use-multiple-databases    try this one..this might help you

Comment: I've already tried that, I wrote it > `tried adding a new connection in config/database.php instead of editing the existing one : same issue`

Comment: Try to first extract some more info in the comment section when you get access to it. Post an answer when you are confident that it can be a solution to the problem. In a case like this, you would first comment, make sure the problem is the one you expose here, and then post an answer.