# Laravel point to local MySQL instead of AWS RDS MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have Laravel project where the previous `.env` file is:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=royo_channel
DB_USERNAME="channel_dev"
DB_PASSWORD="Gum23ho654#@!"
```

I set up AWS RDS MySQL and update the `.env` file to:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=xxx.rds.amazonaws.com
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=channel_order
DB_USERNAME="channel_dev"
DB_PASSWORD="holiday#1"
```

It seems that laravel register this change as when i try to change `DB_PASSWORD` to `holiday#12`.

I will get error 404:

> QLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user
> 'channel_dev'@'102.39.13.304'

But when i am trying function like add user, the data will go to the local database.

Here is my `config/databases.php`:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
        ],
        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL',''),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
        'god' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL',''),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
        'DEV' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL',''),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
        'STAGING' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL',''),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
        'PROD' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL',''),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
        'mysql2' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL',''),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
        'mysql3' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL',''),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],

    ],
```

I have try suggestions from the post below but unable to resolve the issue:
[Laravel 5 app keeps using old database connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30609092/laravel-5-app-keeps-using-old-database-connection)

Comment: You really don't want to be showing any passwords on StackOverflow. Make sure your databases are not using any of these passwords, even if they are in private subnets.

Comment: Thanks @John Rotenstein. Yes the above credentials are slightly modified

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your attempt to help. I found the solution.
Turn out the code is poorly written which is surpising consider that it is from a company with 300 developers.
Basically, they hardcoded the db credentials in the middleware which govern the routing. Hope this is useful for those encountering the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

- make sure you have saved the updated `.env` file correctly + restart your web server/PHP artisan after making the changes to `.env` file
- else try clearing configuration cache by running `php artisan config:cache` (clears cached config files + force Laravel to read the updated file)
- also, double-check that database host + port + username + password + database name in updated .env file are correct.

Comment: Did above steps but unable to resolve the issue

Answer (score -1):

Step 1 : Delete the `config.php` file from (`bootstrap/cache/config.php`) path. (Reason is the old database credentials could be cached there)

Step 2 : Run below commands

```
 composer dump-autoload
 php artisan config:clear
 php artisan config:cache
 php artisan clear-compiled
 php artisan cache:clear
 php artisan view:clear
 php artisan optimize
```

Step 3 : Restart the server

Hope it helps :)